# Google Analytics Get Custom Dimension After Setting One

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics, after setting a custom dimension via:

```
var tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
tracker.set('dimension1', 'myCustomValue');
tracker.send('pageview');
```

I'd like to then GET the custom dimension value for that user when a user navigates to another page, via something like:

```
var tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
var dimension1_value = tracker.get('dimension1');  // 'myCustomValue'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way native to Google Analytics to do this. Values are not stored in cookies anymore and there is no backchannel to the analytics server, get after set only works on the same page.

But of course nothing stops you from setting your own cookie/session storage and store the value(s) there (but then you knew that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah, just was wondering if there was a non-cookie based solution that GA provides. Thanks tho!